# List index out of range: strip

Tags: python, indexing

This code:

```
f1_in = open("1.csv","r")
f1_dict = {}
for line in f1_in:
    l = line.split()
    f1_dict[l[0].strip()] = l[1].strip()
f1_in.close()
```

Getting an error:

```py
list index out of range at f1_dict[l[0].strip()] = l[1].strip()
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? You may want to add a delimiter to `split(',')`?

Comment: Your `l` only one element. Checking your split rule or csv format.

Comment: my purpose is to take two csv files and compare the result and move the matched records and unmatched records to an output file.

Comment: Thanks jmunsch...adding delimiter solves the error

Comment: May I suggest you should use the csv standard python module that handle csv files pretty well : https://docs.python.org/library/csv.html‎ ?